# QueryException in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have converted an sql into laravel query so I came with this below.

```
DB::table('posts')
    ->select('posts.*', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(l.name ORDER BY l.id) as location_name'))
    ->join('locations as l', "posts.location_ids", "=", "l.id")
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(l.id, posts.location_ids) > 0')
    ->where("posts.status", 'active')
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->get();
```

But it gives me an error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laraveltest.posts.title' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `posts`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(l.name ORDER BY l.id) as location_name from `posts` inner join `locations` as `l` on `posts`.`location_ids` = `l`.`id` where FIND_IN_SET(l.id, posts.location_ids) > 0 and `posts`.`status` = active group by `posts`.`id`)
```

When I run this query into any mysql tool, it returns row without any fail. why laravel giving me errors?

Comment: can I ask why you're not making use of laravel's relationships?

Comment: I am new to laravel. I am not able to do so. Can you help me out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762248

Comment: So you have a Post model, and Location Modal?

Comment: yes, posts table have location_ids like comma separated and one post is linked with multiple locations. I have to show one post with multiple location name.

Comment: i want to convert this sql to laravel style SELECT f.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.name ORDER BY l.id) as location_name FROM posts as f INNER JOIN locations as l ON FIND_IN_SET(l.id, f.location_ids) > 0   GROUP BY f.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting in laravel/mysql for laravel look in config/database.php. 
Set strict mode to false

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false,
    ]
```

Laravel is not giving you the error it's just actually enforcing MYSQL rules. PHPMYADMIN and other tools don't force it so that's why you don't get the error.

Comment: Oops, Something is wrong. only one location is coming.

Comment: that is a different issue and not related to this answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason laravel is so good, is because you can get rid of writing huge database queries like this.

You should take some time out to really site down and read the documentation for laravel and how eloquent works. You will be surprised how quickly you pick it up, i promise.

Now for a situation such as your self, you have two models.

Post Model

Location Model

In your Posts model you would create a relationship like so

```
public function location()
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
}
```

and in your Location model you would now define a relationship like so

```
public function post()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Now in your posts_table you need to ensure you have a location_id integer column.

Now what you can do is get the Location instance you want for example:

```
//This will give you the row where id = 1
$location = Location::find(1);
```

Now you can easily do this to access all the posts with that location:

```
foreach($location->posts as $post){
    //Do whatever you want here $post is the object 
    echo $post->title
}
```

And the relationship works on the inverse, example:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
```

Now because this post belongs to only 1 location you can call it like so

```
echo $post->location->column_name_in_location_table
```

Hope this helps kick start your journey to learning laravel!